# Mysql DataTable and CommandBuilder

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I have made a simple console application to clean data in my database table ( blank space etc. )

The application fill the DATATABLE with the selected TABLE from the DATABASE and process it, then i just save the datatable changes ( dataTable.AcceptChanges() )
The problem occurs when i try to update my Database with the edited data in the DATATABLE with the code below ( FROM MSDN ) :

```
    Dim DA As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connessione)
    Dim CB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(DA)

    DA.Update(DT)
```

I do not receive any error, but the database is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx) on the datatable.
This method will change every DataRow [RowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) property from [Modified/Added/Deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) to `Unchanged`. 
As result the `DataAdapter.Update` will not find any row to update/delete/add

The DataTable object is disconnected from the underlying database table from which has received its rows. Calling AcceptChanges will commit the changes to the object IN MEMORY not on the database.
The MySqlDataAdapter with its Update method knows of to connect to the database and apply the changes found on the DataTable. Calling AcceptChanges will prevent this functionality

Comment: My bad, is now one year I work with .net and continue to do blunders of ado.net: |. Thank you very much Steve.